# include class file c++ from subdirectory in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, include, undefined-reference

Hello I try to import c++ class from a subdirectory with xcode, but I receive an error message :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Mother::Mother()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Mother::~Mother()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don’t understand because the code work with this architectory with ‘clang++’ on terminal, may be I miss something to import my file, or may be something to do in setting ?
In the screenshot we see all files is imported. For information there is no problem with template file or function withsub directory , only with classes put in subdirectory, that’s work too when the class file is on the root. I hope it’s clear and if any body have a solution or help for me, that's can be great.

Have a good day.

my configuration :
OSX 10.14.8 / Xcode 11.3.1

Here a simple code to reproduce :

`main.c`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "other/Mother.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Mother Mother;
    return 0;
}
```

`Mother.hpp`

```
#ifndef MOTHER_H
# define MOTHER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Mother {
    public:
        Mother();
        ~Mother();
};
#endif
```

`mother.cpp`

```
#include "./Mother.hpp"

Mother::Mother() {
    return;
}

Mother::~Mother() {
    return;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know XCode, but I assume there is some "project" file that lists all files that are to be compiled. Make sure `Mother.cpp` is listed with `main.cpp`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  yep I added the file, I tested with template and function and that's work. That's happen only with class. and when this one are in subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

In the Open FrameWork forum the solution is giving : https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/import-class-from-directory/35650/6

When folder is imported with file, it's necessary to add the build phase preferences
[image]